iOS: didReceiveRemoteNotification Only Works in Background on Devices in Developer Mode
I am facing an issue with the didReceiveRemoteNotification function on iOS 16 and 17, where it only triggers in the background on iPhones set to Developer Mode. Below are the details:
Environment:
iOS versions: 16 and 17
Devices tested: iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 17.4), iPhone 13 Pro (iOS 16.5.1 and 17.4)
Xcode and project settings: Background modes are enabled for remote notifications
Expected Behavior:
A silent notification should activate the didReceiveRemoteNotification function, which is expected to perform certain actions including playing a sound.
Expected Behavior:
didReceiveRemoteNotification being called so I can handle the notification.
Actual Behavior:
On devices in Developer Mode (e.g., iPhone 14 Pro with iOS 17.4 and iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 16.5.1 after enabling Developer Mode), the didReceiveRemoteNotification function is triggered correctly. However, on a standard iPhone 13 (iOS 17.4) not set in Developer Mode, didReceiveRemoteNotification does not get called. Instead, applicationDidBecomeActive is occasionally called.
Code Snippet:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) async -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
    Logger.log(function: "didReceiveRemoteNotification", message:"application: \(application.debugDescription), userInfo: \(userInfo.debugDescription)")
    let notification = NotificationParser.from(userInfo: userInfo)

    guard notification.type.isEmpty == false else {
        Logger.log(function:"Notification Handler", message: "Notification type is empty")
        return .failed
    }

    NotificationService.handleNotification(userInfo: userInfo)
    return .newData
}

Notification Payload:
{
    "aps": {
        "content-available": 1
    },
    "id": "test",
    "action": "actionA",
    "body": "Sample body text to be used internally",
    "type": "typeA",
    "title": "Notification Title Example"
}

Troubleshooting Steps Tried:

Ensuring background app refresh and notifications are enabled on all devices.
Checking that the project settings are configured correctly for background modes.
Try to use the didReceiveRemoteNotification with completion parameter or with async return

Has anyone else encountered this behavior? Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue or how to fix it?

Are your certificates set up correctly for your test cases? Development builds, testflight builds and release builds can all have different certificates and require the corresponding info be included when sending the push. In general, can you verify that the push is arriving at the device at all? Does the system show it if you don't implement this function?

Yes, I am using the TestFlight especially to test in the Production APNS environment. Since the Development APNS Environment I have to put the Device in Developer mode and when I do that the Silent Notification work

Sometimes I feel like I'm dealing with a buggy system, but it might just be iOS limiting notification delivery.

Note that silent notifications are rate limited. It is possible that this rate limit is not applied to developer devices.  How many notifications are you sending?

I am experiencing the similar problem. It doesn't work in release mode. What's even more strange is that when I send a silent push to my device, the app badge gets updated. So something must reach the device.
